# No livestreams via Google_Service_YouTube (google/apiclient)

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am trying to incorporate YouTube (videos and live streams) into our media site. I'm using, based on PHP, *google/apiclient:^2.0*

So far, I successfully accomplished authentication and authorization via OAuth and retrieving an list of uploaded on-demand videos already in the respective channel of my Google/Youtube user. Even managing offline access without recurring forced logins works.

Nonetheless, retrieving current live streams, and I must emphasize that the stream is active and can be watched in Youtube's dashboard, won't work. The live source is pushed to Youtube via Wowza 4.7, which works flawlessly.

This is the snippet responsible for fetching data:

```php
public function livestreams()
    {
        try {
            $this->_loadToken();

            $this->setService(new \Google_Service_YouTube($this->getClient()));

            $streamsResponse = $this->getService()->liveStreams->listLiveStreams('id,snippet', array(
                'mine' => 'true',
            ));


        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            \Log::error($e->getMessage());
            return [];
        }
        return $streamsResponse;
    }
```

The result of this query:

```
Google_Service_YouTube_LiveStreamListResponse {#416 ▼
  #collection_key: "items"
  +etag: ""XXXXXXXX""
  +eventId: null
  #itemsType: "Google_Service_YouTube_LiveStream"
  #itemsDataType: "array"
  +kind: "youtube#liveStreamListResponse"
  +nextPageToken: null
  #pageInfoType: "Google_Service_YouTube_PageInfo"
  #pageInfoDataType: ""
  +prevPageToken: null
  #tokenPaginationType: "Google_Service_YouTube_TokenPagination"
  #tokenPaginationDataType: ""
  +visitorId: null
  #internal_gapi_mappings: []
  #modelData: []
  #processed: []
  +"pageInfo": Google_Service_YouTube_PageInfo {#417 ▶}
  +"items": []
}
```

So `items` is empty, whereas I expect to find exactly one item, namely the currently active and watchable live stream I push to YouTube.

Is this a flaw in the API or is there a fundamental misunderstanding on my side?

Comment: can you try api explorer to check result is coming or not

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22id%22%2C%22mine%22%3Atrue%7D#try-it

Comment: I just did... and the result is the same, `items` is empty. I double checked that the live stream is up and running.

Comment: so it means you dont have problem in code may be live stream data is not coming at a time ..... can i know the time of live stream you have started in youtube?

Comment: Started it today, about two hours ago...

Comment: I found that some others have seemingly identical problems as well: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69732600

Comment: hey can you start your stream using this method and check its working or not.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2907883?hl=en